# How do I pass a parameter string in a URL to a Python function in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am a **GAE** and **Python** newbie.  I am not able to pass a string parameter from my HTML page to a Python function *(it works for integer parameters though)*.

I have the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8094/papers/xyz
```

In `main()` I have:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', homepage.ViewHomePage),
('/about', aboutpage.ViewAboutPage),
    ('/papers/([\w]+)', PaperList)
],
            config=config,
            debug=True)
```

The function is defined as:

```
class PaperList(BaseHandler):

    def get(self, param1):
```

In `app.yaml` I have:

```
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

This does not work.  However, if I just change the parameter from a string to an integer, then it works. *(I am not doing anything with the parameter yet, just want it to accept the string parameter.)*

Can someone tell me what I have to change to allow it to work with a string parameter and also point me to where the documentation explains how to pass parameters through `main()`?

I am using **Python 2.7**.

Comment: You have mapped that URL somewhere, either in main.py or in app.yaml. Please show that code.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I corrected the original question to show main() and app.yaml.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\d` only matches decimal digits. Did you mean to use `\w` instead? Also, no square brackets.

Comment: Thanks.  the \w did it.  I do not understand about the no square brackets.  I have around 40 lines in the main().  I have included a few more lines in my original questions to make it more understandable.  Do you still think I should drop the square brackets?  It works as is.

Comment: Square brackets are used to match multiple characters in the same location, e.g. `[abc]` will match either of `a`, `b`, or `c`; A class specifier such as `\d` or `\w` matches multiple characters on its own.

Answer (score 0):

you also have the option of passing urlencoded data such as yourapp.appspot.com/papers?keyword=helloworld

and get it in your handler with:
keyword = self.request.GET.get('keyword')
or 
keyword = self.request.POST.get('keyword') depending on your request method.

you can also pass json data in the body of a AJAX post and use json to deserialize it into python data. To validate this kind of data, I recommend voluptuous.